# What is creating these Django database log entries?

Tags: django

My development server's Django database log files are quite large because a particular event is being logged once every minute:

```
[10/Sep/2017 21:02:02] DEBUG [django.db.backends:89] (0.001) DELETE FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."expire_date" < '2017-09-10T21:02:02.514421+00:00'::timestamptz; args=(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 21, 2, 2, 514421, tzinfo=<UTC>),)
[10/Sep/2017 21:03:02] DEBUG [django.db.backends:89] (0.002) DELETE FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."expire_date" < '2017-09-10T21:03:02.265801+00:00'::timestamptz; args=(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 21, 3, 2, 265801, tzinfo=<UTC>),)
[10/Sep/2017 21:04:02] DEBUG [django.db.backends:89] (0.002) DELETE FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."expire_date" < '2017-09-10T21:04:02.033147+00:00'::timestamptz; args=(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 21, 4, 2, 33147, tzinfo=<UTC>),)
```

My settings file contains these session-related directives:

```
DEBUG = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ...
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60
# Refresh session state with every request.  This effectively creates
# a "sliding" session expiration.  A user will remain signed in so
# long as they send at least one request every SESSION_COOKIE_AGE minutes.
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # ...
]
```

I don't have anything session-related in my LOG settings.  What is causing these DEBUG entries and is there any way to disable them or at least reduce their frequency?

Comment: You have `DEBUG` set to `True` which might tell the logger to dump lots of things. Running `DEBUG = True` in production is a bad idea anyways because you can leak information like a sieve. If your dev server is dev-y enough to be dev, just throw away those files, of it's supposed to be more production-y, don't run with `DEBUG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The golden answer goes Here add in **settings.py** file.you need delete or comment out these lines,these generate database log entriy

```
 DEBUG = True
 '''
 LOGGING = {
 'version': 1,
 'filters': {
     'require_debug_true': {
         '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
     }
 },
 'handlers': {
     'console': {
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
         'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
     }
 },
 'loggers': {
     'django.db.backends': {
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'handlers': ['console'],
     }
 }
}
'''
```